# Field fails to be renamed

Tags: ms-access

I am working on a code that will create a new field in a table then this new field will be populated with the values from another field with some modifications. When the copy is done then I drop the old column and rename the new populated column with the name of the dropped column. When everything is done then I am adding a foreign key and continue with the next column, but the code gives me an error "Item not found in this collection". When I run the code on first column it works perfectly.

```
    Debug.Print dbDestination.TableDefs(strTableName).Fields("" & strColumn    & "1").Name
```

this is where it breaks

Comment: What does `Debug.Print strColumn  & "1"` show you when encounter that error?  Does it display the name of a field which exists in the table?

Comment: It actually gave me the name of the field that i need

Comment: Why don't you just modify the values without creating new fields. Just read the value, modify it, then write the modified value back.

Comment: The fields have a look up table. To disable the look up  field manually it will take to much time so i decided to do it in code. I am creating a new field and dropping the one with the lookup field. The error that I get i believe is it because there are queries based on those fields